# Free TTF font editor under Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, truetype

Know anything worth trying?

Comment: Asking in an appropriate forum would be "worth trying".

Comment: If you're just looking for free TTF fonts, you can try http://www.dafont.com/ though you should pay close attention to any licenses if you intend to use them commercially.

Answer (score 1):

I can't determine whether it would be "worth trying" for you, but [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/ms-install.html) is a free, open source tool for editing TTF (and other) fonts. It can be built to run under Windows.